# NSWorkspace openFile withApplication does not work with spaces in filename

Tags: cocoa, macos

when using like this

```
[ [NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] openFile:fileName withApplication:appName];
```

and fileName contains spaces

the other app complains that cannot open filename

I do not have source to other app

but when I launch the same app with `NSTask` it can correctly read the complete file path

i've tried surrounding the file path with quotes but it didn't help

Comment: The spaces might need to be escaped before you can use them. You should read the NSWorkspace class reference, it will be more clear on what the method wants

Comment: if i escape " " to "\\ " i get this 2/8/11 2:12:23 PM  LSOpenFromURLSpec() returned -43 for application /Applications/ABC Utilities/ABC Viewer.app path /Users/sajidkhan/Documents/ABC\ Library/MAH00031_trimmed_i0o7018.MP4.

Comment: There is nothing in NSWorkspace document that suggests that spacing might be needed [link] http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSWorkspace_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Answer (score 0):

Definitely it's not the problem of `NSWorkspace`. You don't need any shell-escaping there. `NSWorkspace` does not launch the other app via a shell, anyway. And I could open in Safari an html file whose name contains a space, using `NSWorkspace`.

So, the problem lies in the other app. What's that app? If you don't have the source, you can't do anything about it, other than to complain the maker/author of that program.